# Connect Cyrus Imap to AD

Tags: active-directory, email, email-server, ldap, cyrus

I am trying to connect Cyrus IMAP to an Active Directory following [this](https://www.tekfik.com/kb/linux/mail/postfix-active-directory-ldap-authentication-with-cyrus-sasl-on-linux) instruction.
I have set `ldap_servers` to `ldap://myad.domain.com` but if I telnet on the Cyrus Server it returns `cyrus.domain.com`.

Am I doing something wrong here or is it supposed to return this?

How can I make Cyrus Server to get Mails from my Users in the AD?

How can I connect to those inboxes?